# Nested If compile issue in Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I am attempting to get an Excel workbook to print out X copies of Y number of pages based on certain cell parameters. I had "working" code, however it would send too many print commands to the printer so what I am trying to do is have it Select each applicable worksheet and just send one batch print command.

I have tried selecting pages and storing them in an array but I wasn't having as much luck so I decided to go with the below code. The code in the comments is what I have changed from working code. Every time I go to compile it I get a "**Compile error: End If without block If**" error. I also have added a comment where the Debugger ends up highlighting and throwing me the compile error. I looked at indenting, verified the number of "If"s and "End If"s, made sure I had no single line "If...THen..." statements in my code, and combed forums for something close. Everything I find that is close does not end up fitting this issue.

I am looking for some guidance and for another set of eyes on this code. I am including the whole code minus variable assignments. I have never posted to Stack as I have always been able to figure out what I need based on other posts but I am throwing in the towel with this one. Any help would be appreciated! I am hoping its just a stupid mistake on my part and not a drastic error.

```
Application.ScreenUpdating = False

If Not IsEmpty(copies) Then
    For j = 1 To copies
        If vShts = "0" Then
            Sheets("BLANK ORDER").PrintOut
        Else

        '####Beginning of changed code####
        With ActiveWorkbook
        ThisWorkbook.Sheets("GO BACK PAGE 1").Select
        If vShts > 1 Then
            For lShCnt = 2 To vShts
                ThisWorkbook.Sheets("GO BACK PAGE " & lShCnt).Select False
            Next lShCnt
        End If
        With ActiveWorkbook
            ActiveSheet.Range("A1:S39").Select
            Selection.PrintOut preview:=True
        End With
        ThisWorkbook.Sheets(Sheet1.Name).Select
        '####End of changed code####

    End If   '<- This "End If" is where the Debugger highlights it hanging up on
Next j
Else
    If vShts = "0" Then
        Sheets("BLANK ORDER").PrintOut
    Else
        With ActiveWorkbook
            For i = 1 To vShts
                Sheets("GO BACK PAGE " & i).PrintOut
            Next i
        End With
    End If
End If

ThisWorkbook.Sheets(Sheet1.Name).Select

Application.ScreenUpdating = True
```

Comment: You're missing an `End With` exactly where your end of changed code comment is located.

Comment: I would say there is extra `With ActiveWorkbook` line. More of that, all `With ... End With` blocks within changed code are not used, and can be simply removed.

Comment: Thank you all for pointing this out! I checked the "IF" statements a multitude of times as that was what was being called out but just gave an apparently cursory glance at the "With" statements.

Answer (score 0):

This is a common problem many beginners hit one day or another, and other than not-so-constructive "well, just follow the language syntax properly!", there are actually real techniques to avoid this problem.

The easiest one to pick up is *indentation* - or rather, *consistency* in indentation.

### Indentation

The problem starts here:

```
    If vShts = "0" Then
        Sheets("BLANK ORDER").PrintOut
    Else

    '####Beginning of changed code####
    With ActiveWorkbook
```

The indentation should have been incremented right there:

```
    If vShts = "0" Then
        Sheets("BLANK ORDER").PrintOut
    Else

        '####Beginning of changed code####
        With ActiveWorkbook
```

The key to easy and correct pairing of `If...End If` blocks - or *any* blocks, really, is consistent indentation.

Whenever you see a "block opener" where the next line of code isn't indented, you can expect this problem to show up. Like this `With` block that is never terminated and causes the compile error you're getting - because the compiler reaches `End If` but was expecting `End With`:

```
    With ActiveWorkbook
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("GO BACK PAGE 1").Select
    ...
End If
```

---

The other technique is a bit harder to put into practice, but really pays off in the long run, when you start really *naming things* and structure your scripts and programs.

#### Smaller Procedures

Large procedures that do many things, are much harder to "get right" than they need to be. One way to make a large procedure easier to manage, is to split it up into smaller procedures that do fewer things. So instead of this:

```
If condition Then
   'do stuff
   'do more stuff
   'some more stuff
Else
   'do other stuff
End If
```

You can pull the content of a conditional branch into its own smaller, more specialized procedure:

```
If condition Then
    DoStuff
Else
    DoOtherStuff
End If
```

You can do this by introducing new `Sub` statements, outside the macro/procedure you're already in:

```
Private Sub DoStuff()
   'do stuff
   'do more stuff
   'some more stuff
End Sub

Private Sub DoOtherStuff()
   'do other stuff
End Sub
```

You can then pass *parameters* between procedures, and later use `Function` procedures that evaluate these parameters and return a value accordingly, and things get really, really interesting once you master these building blocks. Keep going!